# Why do I need to write let to declare a variable?

Tags: types, programming-languages, type-inference, type-systems, rust

In Haskell I don't need to write anything to declare a variable. In C++ I need to write `auto`, which as far as I know works in an analogous way to rust's `let`.

- Isn't it a step back to use `let` to declare a variable?:

  ```
  let hi = "hi";
  ```
- Type inference and the assignment operator should be enough, or aren't they?:

  ```
  hi = "hi";
  ```

I'm just asking because the first thing that caught my attention while skimming through Rust's tutorial were the `let`'s everywhere. I felt like, I shouldn't be needing to type it! The compiler already knows that I'm declaring a variable! For declaring uninitialized variables, one could argue that it might be nice to declare them with a type. But again, it's optional, a matter of style. The compiler can deduce the type at first use, and don't compile if it's not used and hence can't deduce the type.

- What is the rationale behind *forcing* the users to write let? In particular, what is the rationale against making let optional?

Comment: I don't agree that the question should be closed. Unless some special source comes up (@dbaupp - surprise us?), I'll wager it's a matter of style - it adds readability, and most languages have such a keyword (`let`, `var`, `auto` etc.).

Comment: @RamonSnir thanks! Of course there are use cases for the keyword `let`, e.g. declaring an uninitialized variable. But making it mandatory everywhere seems just overly verbose to me (Haskell does pretty fine without it). I can imagine how some combination of obscure C++ rules would require such a keyword to exists in C++. But retrofitting an existing language is different from designing a new language from scratch.

Comment: Haskell has `let .. in ..` **and** `.. where ..`, what do you mean?

Comment: @RamonSnir Yes, I mean that in _most contexts_ I don't have to write it, but I can if I want to make it explicit. Sorry about the above, it should be interpreted as "Haskell does pretty fine without making it mandatory at every variable declaration".

Comment: I have a feeling there are at least 2 things going on here. Rust is big about being explicit, so variables should be explicitly declared (so the compiler knows about them, and their scope, rather than having to infer it), and the core team is also keen on having an unambiguous LL(k) (for small k) grammar (not sure if this is super important here). (@RamonSnir, I don't have much more info than you. :) )

Comment: @dbaupp I can understand the rationale behind being explicit, but I'm also not sure if the syntax becomes ambiguous when one omits the `let` keyword. I don't think so. It might be that having `let` simplifies the life of 3rd-party tool developers. However, any 3rd-party tool developing their own parser and semantic analyzer for e.g. syntax highlighting or refactoring is doing it wrong anyways (they should use rust's compiler parser/semantic analyzer ala llvm way).

Comment: @gnzlbg, removing `let` (probably) wouldn't make it ambiguous, just harder and slower to parse, since the grammar is not (necessarily) LL(1)/LL(2)/... then. (I'm not actually sure of this though, I guess it's mainly explicitness.)

Comment: Hm, just thought of this: the pattern grammar is different to the expression/statement grammar, and `let` introduces a pattern context (i.e. you can pattern match in a let expression.), but it wouldn't be possible to decide that one has a pattern-matching assignment with finite look-ahead without `let`. (Also having `let x = 1` means that declaring a mutable variable with `let mut x = 1` is slightly more consistent than `x = 1` and `mut x = 1`, which is possibly a little nice?)

Comment: @dbaupp Indeed, pattern matching without let doesn't seem possible. Thanks! I guess that knowing why I have to write let makes writing it a bit less disturbing for me.

Comment: @dbaupp: By my understanding, if code contains a `let mut`, a conditional statement that may assign a new value to that variable, and a read of the variable, the original value may or may not be seen by the later read (depending upon whether the value was rewritten), but any value assigned with a non-mut `let` will either *always* or *never* be overwritten before any particular attempt to read a variable by that name.  Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I am not so sure about grammar considerations (I think omitting it would be fine, grammar-wise, just more complex), but `let` and variable assignment are not the same thing in Rust. `let` is 1. pattern matching, 2. binding introducing. You can only do `x = 3` if x is a mutable slot, but you can *always* do `let x = 3`, it introduces a new binding of a possibly different type and mutability. Removing `let` would make the current binding semantics impossible. It would also make patterns much more difficult, if not impossible. For example, `let (a, b) = some_fn_returning_tuple();`.

Answer (score 1):

This is inferred from ML syntax and in ML you don't declare variables, you declare bindings to values.

So it's just a convention, but unless you declare it as mutable, you must think of it as a binding. I don't think that there is a reason to it, but just to make it better "parseable" and keep the language clean.